# how to say that I don't enjoy the spotlight

Tags: idiom-requests

I am trying to convey a subtle message that I'm not particularly keen at giving a presentation while also allowing the possibility that I can give it after all if the other party so desires. As reason for preferring not to give the presentation I would like to cite my public shyness.

I thought I could say something like:

*I can give the presentation if you find the results interesting but it's really up to you;
    I don't enjoy the spotlight so I don't really mind one way or the other.*

... but I am worrying that this might come across as a bit arrogant in the sense of implying that my presentation (if given) would be the focus of the event. Any other way to put it?

Comment: I probably wouldn't choose to give the presentation myself, but I could be talked into it if you think people would find it interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I don't like being the centre of attention but if you insist...
- I tend to shun the limelight but if you can't find anyone else...
- to be frank/honest I find presentations to be nerve wracking experiences, but if you need someone count me in.

But your original phrase

> ... I don't **enjoy the spotlight** so I don't really mind one way or the other.

is perfectly fine.

Comment: In my opinion it's a bit of a contradiction.  If you really  didn't mind then you wouldn't say anything about it.  Op *does* mind and would prefer not to do it, but will if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to be behind the scenes,* or *.. backstage.*

Comment: Or "I prefer to *remain on the sidelines*" (a common idiom referencing American football).

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer not to give a presentation (because they make me nervous/uncomfortable), but I am willing to do it if you want me to.

Or perhaps ...if you think it's important.